# How to write an orthogonal matrix as multiplication of two orthogonal and symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

I know an orthogonal matrix is multiplication of at most n Householder reflection, which is both orthogonal and symmetric.But how to write an orthogonal matrix as multiplication of two matrix and they are both orthogonal and symmetric?

Comment: What makes you think such a decomposition is possible? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Every real orthogonal matrix is orthogonally similar to its [real Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices), which is a direct sum of $I,-I$ and $2\times2$ rotation matrices. Now we are done because $I=(I)(I),\,-I=(-I)(I)$ and
$$
\pmatrix{\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta&\cos\theta}=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1}\pmatrix{\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\ -\sin\theta&-\cos\theta}.
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate? Similarity means $Q^{-1}AQ$, giving three matrices, not two.